# Implementing dynamic text on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-text

I basically need to develop a UITextView that lets the user use a combination of bold and plain text. I know there are a variety of ways this can be accomplished, ie coreText, etc. Does anyone have any recommendations on the simplest way to accomplish this goal? I need to be able to control the spacing between the text as the user enters in text as well as allow the user to enter it in bold / plain text. Keep in mind I also I want to make my app iOS4 compatible.

Comment: There's no view made by apple, that's for sure.

Comment: Check out http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am too developing a rich text app and after a lot of looking around I found the easiest way is to use a `UIWebView`, set content editable and use javascript.

There is a [great tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/) on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep this in mind, but this can only be used in ios5.